# write string to file txt in Android but file is always empty

Tags: java, android, file

I want to create String to txt file that i got from textfield. the file created but it's always empty. i don't know what is wrong. it's work if i manually write the string : out.write("text"), but when i took the text from textview, it's always empty. please help.

this is code to created file :

```
        String fname =  t2.getText().toString()+".txt";
        String text =  t3.getText().toString();
        String fpath =  t.getText().toString();
            try {
                File root = new File(fpath);
                if (!root.exists()) {
                    root.mkdirs();
                }
                File gpxfile = new File(root, fname);
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(writer);
                out.println(text);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Berhasil menyimpan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
```

this is where `text = t3.getText().toString()` came from :

```
 t3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.saveText);
```

Comment: Time to learn to debug.

Comment: i'm newbie. could u please teach me how?

Comment: @m0skit0 Use breakpoints and then run in Debug mode

Comment: i don't understand. i'm using Android Studio btw

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html

Comment: do one thing show toast message just before out.println(text) and show this text in toast and check as you are getting text or not

Comment: @ranysella Or else you can also use *Log* to check what text contains.

Comment: and also use out.write(text) instead of out.println()

Comment: i used out.write(text) before, but didn't work. that's why i tried to use println

Comment: @vickyexpert i got an empty text from toast message before out.println :(

Comment: it means text not stores in your textview or may be you are assigning wrong id with t3

Comment: Please tell what you type in in those EditTexts. Especially fname and fpath.

Comment: `empty text from toast message`. Ok. Debug further.

Comment: i tried to rewrite text in t3 to another textview by testt3.setText(t3.toString()); the text appeared.

Comment: `root.mkdirs();`. You should check the return value. And display a toast if false. And not continue if false.

Comment: i can't do the debug because it says "Unable to locate adb within SDK". i used to try my app by creating an apk

Comment: @ranysella post your full code with xml file for better help

Comment: Its really time you tell us the absolute path of that file. And how you check that it exists.

Comment: `t3.toString())`. That is not the text that appears in a textview.

Comment: i create a directory explorer to choose directory to save the file. so i'm pretty sure the path exists

Comment: t3.getText().toString() , typo

Comment: Yes but if you want help then tell exact path. Just answer the questions. What is the value of `root.getAbsolutePath()` ?

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/textfile/

Comment: And does `gpxfile.getAbsolutePath()` exist after writing?

Comment: yes it does. but empty

Comment: Well if the toast displays it empty you know where you have to look.

Comment: where?? i'm sorry i'm really new at these

Comment: `text = t3.getText().toString()`. Toast it right after this line.

Comment: And put a toast in that catch block.

Comment: so how to get the text then?

Comment: t3 is the wrong one. Try to set a text in it to see.

Comment: i got the problem, i did set text to t3 by getExtra from intent. but i lost the Extra because i open another activity to select directory. then after open it i get back to previous activity and then the Extra for t3 lost.

Comment: how to save the extra from intent? i used savepreferenced, singletop, etc. but my app crashed